# AlertDialog, Problems with editText components

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I tried to use that AlertDialog thing but I got an error if I try to access the editText components. I have my own layout with two editText fields.

It seems that I cannot access the components.

I know there are lots of questions about this stuff but I didn't found a hint how to solve my problem.

Code:

```
protected void showLoginDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_laylout, null, false))
    .setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Dialog f = (Dialog) dialog;

            EditText txtLoginUserPhoneNumber = (EditText) f.findViewById(R.id.txt_LoginUserPhoneNumber);
            EditText txtLoginUserPW = (EditText) f.findViewById(R.id.txt_LoginUserPW);

            /* ERROR HERE! */
            Log.i("CHAT: ", txtLoginUserPhoneNumber.getText().toString() + " " + txtLoginUserPW.getText().toString());
        }
    })
    .setNeutralButton("Create new account",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });      
    builder.create().show();
}
```

EDIT:

LocCat:

```
06-23 14:41:28.495: W/dalvikvm(21233): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b04930)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at com.example.listviewexample.ListViewExampleActivity$2.onClick(ListViewExampleActivity.java:96)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-23 14:41:28.505: E/AndroidRuntime(21233):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does Someone has a hint for me?

Comment: Please post the logcat trace for the error.

Comment: What error? try to put it in a try-catch and find out what type of exception it is..

Comment: With try catch I get the following: 06-23 14:43:30.245: I/CHAT:(21704): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the views from a DialogInterface object. Instead of initializing the views in onClick(), you can do this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_laylout, null, false);

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Dialog f = (Dialog) dialog;

            EditText txtLoginUserPhoneNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_LoginUserPhoneNumber);
            EditText txtLoginUserPW = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_LoginUserPW);

           ...
        }
    })
```

Comment: I still get the Exception: 06-23 15:10:28.635: I/CHAT:(23312): java.lang.NullPointerException. I have to use final in front of view decleration

Comment: okay, that's strange. It works for txt_LoginUserPW but for txtLoginUserPhoneNumber I got Null as ref. I will try to figrue out why.

Comment: I figured out the problem...... I got a wrong component via R.id..... Thanks guys for helping me out.